# Do while loop error message (identity error)

Tags: c, function, do-while, cs50

I'm trying to use this code to prompt the user to provide with a number and put the condition that the answer should be between 1 and 23(inclusive). However as i tried with the `do-while` loop, it seems to be throwing back an error I am not familiar with.

My code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "cs50.h"
int n;
do
{
    n = get_int("Enter a number: ");
}
while (n < 0 || n > 23);
```

The Error:

```
hello.c:5:1: error: expected identifier or '{'
do
^
hello.c:10:1: error: expected identifier or '{'
while (n < 0 || n > 23);
^
```

Comment: no images of code please, _please_

Comment: where is main()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't that the syntax of your loop is wrong. The problem is that you didn't put it in any function, so the compiler didn't expect the loop in that context. `int n;` is valid outside of functions, that's why the error happens when the loop starts. Try something like this:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "cs50.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // the program starts here; "main" is the function that is run when the program is started
    int n;
    do {
        n = get_int("Enter a number: ");
    }
    while (n < 0 || n > 23);
    // TODO: do something useful with the input
    return 0; // The convention is that returning 0 means that everything went right
}
```

Note how the code is now inside the `main` function instead of just standing there alone.